# How to pass the key focus to the other item in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Here are the code in my QML files:

**main.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: window    
    color: "white"; width: 240; height: 150

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent; spacing: 15

        MyClickableWidget {
            focus: true             //set this MyWidget to receive the focus
            color: "lightblue"
        }
        MyClickableWidget {
            color: "palegreen"
        }
    }    
}
```

**MyClickableWidget.qml**

```
FocusScope {
    id: scope
    //i try to set true instead of the mouse event
    //focus: true
    //FocusScope needs to bind to visual properties of the children
    property alias color: rectangle.color
    x: rectangle.x; y: rectangle.y
    width: rectangle.width; height: rectangle.height

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "lightsteelblue"; width: 175; height: 25; radius: 10; antialiasing: true
        Text { id: label; anchors.centerIn: parent }
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_A)
                label.text = 'Key A was pressed'
            else if (event.key == Qt.Key_B)
                label.text = 'Key B was pressed'
            else if (event.key == Qt.Key_C)
                label.text = 'Key C was pressed'
        }
    }
    MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: { scope.focus = true } }
}
```

I have two question about this code:

**First.** The first component have been set `focus: true`. Then when press key, it will show the text. But I am not clear that why clicking either `MyClickableWidget` gives it focus and the other widget loses the focus? Does the click event give the focus to the component? If yes, which part will get the focus (`scope` or `rectangle`)?

Also, in my opinion, the line showed as following is to set `scope.focus` to `true`. So, I comment out this line, the insert a line `focus = true` in the `scope`. However it doesn't work, can not pass the key focus to the other item. Why?

```
// MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: { scope.focus = true } }
```

The result is the same. I don't know why the code need this line.

**Second.** In focus scopes, if the children have the `focus: true`, all parent and root will automatically be set `focus: true`? if not in focus scopes, is the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a `FocusScope` in the first place? Your code can be greatly simplified if you get rid of it.

An important thing to know is that within a `FocusScope`, **only one item at a time can have focus**. The application window behaves like a `FocusScope` itself. To keep it simple, if an item gains focus, the item that previously had focus automatically loses it.

**FocusRect.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    width: 175;
    height: 25;
    radius: 10;

    Text { id: label; anchors.centerIn: parent }

    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (event.key == Qt.Key_A)
            label.text = 'Key A was pressed'
        else if (event.key == Qt.Key_B)
            label.text = 'Key B was pressed'
        else if (event.key == Qt.Key_C)
            label.text = 'Key C was pressed'
    }

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: parent.forceActiveFocus()
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow {

    width: 960
    height: 540

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent; 
        spacing: 15

        FocusRect {
            focus: true             //set this MyWidget to receive the focus
            color: "lightblue"
        }
        FocusRect {
            color: "palegreen"
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior here is stragihtforward. An item must have activeFocus to get key events. For an Item to have activeFocus set to true, two condition must be met

- Item itself has its focus property set to true
- Its closest FocusScope parent has activeFocus or it has no focusScope parent, and the application window has active focus.

In this simple example, setting the focus of `MyClickableWidget` to true will also set its activeFocus to true (no parent FocusScope), making it able to get KeyEvents.

In answer to your second question, within a `FocusScope`, setting an item's focus to true will have no side effects. However, forcing it to gain activeFocus (by calling `forceActiveFocus()` on it) will make all its FocusScope parents gain activeFocus (and consequently set focus to true for all FocusScope in the item's parent hierarchy)

Conversely, if a FocusScope gains active focus and have a child with focus set to true, the child activeFocus will also be set to true.

Comment: Thank you very much. About your code , i have a question. In MouseArea,you have set parent to get active focus, here the parent is the instantiation of FocusRect ? I mean if you click the second rect, the second rect is the parent? Also, the code i showed is from QT doc,  As you said "if a FocusScope gains active focus and have a child with focus set to true, the child activeFocus also be true"Can I understand it as setting [onClicked: { scope.focus = true } ] in my code, and if i click the second item, the scope.focus have be set to true and the first one to false?But why first one is false?

Comment: I mean why first one lose active focus and the second gain it. If firstly i click the first item, its  scope.focus have be set to true, then i click second one, at  that time two item's scope.focus are true,right? So why the second on have the active focus?

Comment: Within a focusScope (or a top level window), only one item at a time can have focus. So when one item gains focus, every other item automatically loses it (except if they"re in a focusScope, in that case, the FocusScope loses focus, but the item inside it keep it. At this time, its activeFocus is false though)

Comment: Thank you.①About your code, when you click second item,the Rectangle(parent) have ActiveFocus. However,second FocusRect doesn't set focus: true. Why the second FocusRect can gain ActiveFocus? ②Also, in my code, i just set scope.focus to true(not forceActiveFocus) in mouse event. Why the second one can gain the ActiveFocus? I comment out the mouse event, and insert a line focus = true in the scope. However it doesn't work, can not pass the key focus to the other item. Why?

Comment: ①You have mentioned that an Item to have activeFocus set to true, two condition must be met,Item itself has its focus property set to true. However, second one[FocusRect {
            color: "palegreen"
        }] haven't set to be true

Comment: forceActiveFocus makes the Item and all its parent focusScope gain focus, therefore the item gains activeFocus. For simple use case, with no FocusScope involved, it is equivalent to set focus=true.

Comment: I know that,but in your code, you haven't use focusScope, that's why i cannot understand that second one[FocusRect { color: "palegreen" }]  can get  activeFocus. Also, in my code, why  the second one set focus=true can gain activeFocus(if use forceActiveFocus  i can understand)

Comment: If you have NO focusScope, setting focus to true is THE SAME as calling forceActiveFocus, meaning the item will gain focus AND active focus, while every other item loses focus,.

Comment: Please forgive me that i ask you so many questions and thank u very much. But i think you misunderstood my question. For your answer, i have two question.①In the code which you show to me, you haven't use focusScope. And you use mouse event to set Rectangle to gain ActiveFocus. As you said an Item to have activeFocus, two condition must be met,Item itself has its focus property set to true. My question is second one[FocusRect { color: "palegreen" }] haven't set focus to be true.  How can it get ActiveFocus

Comment: ②The second question is about my code which i show it in my question. I use focusScope!  why the second one set focus=true(mouse event) can gain activeFocus(if use forceActiveFocus i can understand)

Comment: Let's try again. Anwswer 1. In the mouseArea onClicked event, I call forceActiveFocus on the mouseArea's parent. This parent is the Root rectangle of the FocusRect component. So when I click on the mouse area, I call forceActiveFocus on the FocusRect. The forceActiveFocus() will, as its name implies, set focus = true and ensure that any existing parent focusScope has also focus set to true. In my example, I could have used onClicked: parent.focus = true, with the SAME result

Comment: Answer 2: In the mouse area, you set focus = true on scope. Scope is the root FocusScope of your MyClickableWidget component. No higher FocusScope component prevent it from gaining activeFocus when it acquires focus, so then again, calling forceActiveFocus, and setting focus to true would be STRICLTY equivalent.

Comment: My advice for simple cases is: do not bother with FocusScope, call forceActiveFocus() when you want to set focus on an item, and that's it.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have almost understood what you said! But just a little question about switching focus to other item! Can I understand it as when i use the mouse to click the item, the item what i click can get the "focus" ,then go forward to check the focus parameter whether it have ActiveFocus or not?(if i click out of item area, nothing have happened). At that case, if i use key event instead of mouse event, i can not switch  focus to other item,right?(Just copy the code from MouseArea{...} to Keys.onPressed:..)

Comment: Key Events and Mouse Event do not work the same way. MouseEvents have nothing to do with focus ; if you click on an enabled MouseArea, it will receive the clickEvent, and the onClicked handler will be called. That's it. Key Events, on the other hand, only work if the items that define the key handler have activeFocus (so only one item at a time). That prevents from typing into two textfield at the same time for instance, which is usually something you want to avoid.